# How to use 'content-for'?

Tags: ember.js

In my index.html I have:

```
<body>
    {{content-for "body}}
    {{content-for "body-footer"}}
</body>
```

How can I put content in the 'body-footer'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current way to add content via `content-for` is to do it [via an addon](http://ember-cli.com/extending/#content). It can be an in-repo addon (`ember g in-repo-addon <name>`). You can find more information in the [Ember CLI](http://ember-cli.com) website, both in "User Guide" and "Extending".